# How can we upgrade Office Web App Server 2010 to 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, office-web-apps

I have Office Web app installed on SharePoint Foundation 2010. I am upgrading the SharePoint to SharePoint Server 2013. While upgrading I am getting the below error

> "Office_viewing_service_cache cannot be upgraded".

Any idea why this is happening?

Is it even possible to upgrade OWA 2010 to 2013 ? Are they even compatible? As far as I researched, the architecture for OWA 2010 and OWA 2013 is different.

How can we upgrade ?

Comment: As far as the new architecture of OWA 2013 is concerned, Microsoft has recommended to create a dedicated server for OWA 2013, so I dont think its a recommended to MIGRATE OWA 2010 to 2013.

Comment: Yeah. But are there any workarounds? If we are to upgrade SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and while doing so we would like to use OWA 2010 instead of the recommended 2013. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's true that Office Web Apps server 2010 is very different from Office Web Apps 2013. OWA 2010 should run on a SharePoint Server and a OWA 2013 should run on stand-alone server(s).

The main reason for this is that other server products (Lync, Exchange and so on) also can use OWA.

[image]

For this reason, you should install a new Office Web Apps Server (or Farm actually) that you connect to from your SharePoint Farm.

The tool to use is (as always) PowerShell.

When your Office Web Apps farm is installed and configured, you run several scripts from a SharePoint Server.

```
# Connect to Office Web Apps Server
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName OfficeWebAppsServer -AllowHTTP

# Set to run over HTTP
Set-SPWOPIZone -zone internal-http

# Allow HTTP
(Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig).AllowOAuthOverHttp 

$config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
$config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$config.Update()
```

Depending on your security policy, you allow http or https. The default is https.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Do you know if there any workarounds for keeping the OWA 2010 while upgrading to SharePoint 2013? What I am trying to know is if It is possible when I say that I want to upgrade my Sharepoint 2010 to 2013 but want to keep my previous OWA 2010. Is this possible?

Comment: @Raxak You already have to create a new SharePoint Farm since in-place upgrade isn't possible from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. That way you can have both SP Farms and OWA 2010 and 2013 running in parallell. It's the best approach since you don't have to worry about loosing content or settings.

Comment: Ok. that made sense. But right now I am getting an error while migrating from Shareponint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I am thinking this error is due to  the presence of OWA 2010 ? Therefore, in order to have successful migration to SP 2013, will I need to uninstall OWA 2010 first ? or is there any other way ?

Comment: @Raxak I don't think that kind of dependency would make an error while migrating. Does it say your missing a Site Template (very common) or something else?

Comment: No there was no error related to Site Template missing. The error was related to "Office_viewing_service_cache cannot be upgraded"

Comment: @Raxak Hmm. Looks like you have to disconnect Office Web Apps to make things work. But before, start googling the error message, 'cause I'm sure you're not the first one with this error :-)